# counting confusion_matrix in python

Tags: python-3.x, math, machine-learning, deep-learning

I wan to calculate calculate `True_Positive, False_Positive,False_Negative, True_Negative` for three categories. I used to have two classes `Cat` `Dog` and this is the way i used to calculate my confusion_matrix

```
    Y_pred has either a cat or dog 
    y_true has either a cat or dog  
    confusion_matrix_output =confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred) 
    True_Positive = confusion_matrix_output[0][0]
    False_Positive = confusion_matrix_output[0][1]
    False_Negative = confusion_matrix_output[1][0]
    True_Negative = confusion_matrix_output[1][1]
```

---

Now i have three classes 'Cat' 'Dog' 'rabbit'

```
Y_pred has Cat Dog rabbit
y_true has Cat Dog rabbit
```

How to calculate True_Positive, False_Positive,False_Negative, True_Negative ???

Comment: For common things like this, there's always a module properly written before:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

Comment: I am using it in my code mentioned above confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)

Comment: When you have more than one class, then there's the recall and precision you work with, not the T/F-P/N anymore. With two classes you had chosen Cat to be positive and Dog to be negative, with three classes the binary logic does not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Now you have three classes, so it's not just positives and negatives anymore. 
You have to look at:
Cat predicted as a cat, Dog predicted as Dog, Rabbit predicted as Rabbit, Dog predicted as cat, Cat predicted as Dog, and so on. You'll have 3 by 3 confusion matrix for this situation. Confusion matrix size is n by n, where n is the number of classes

`sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix` abstracts away all that and creates an n by n matrix for you. Try this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix_output =confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred) 
Cat_P_Cat = confusion_matrix_output[0][0]
```